# ESP-IDF Github Actions: docker: command not found Error: Process completed with exit code 127

Tags: docker, github-actions, esp32, esp-idf

I'm building my first CI for GitHub Action and I have problem with building the code.

```
name: Build

on: [push, pull_request, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  build-esp-idf-component:
    name: Build with ESP-IDF ${{ matrix.idf_ver }} for ${{ matrix.idf_target }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        # The version names here correspond to the versions of espressif/idf Docker image.
        # See https://hub.docker.com/r/espressif/idf/tags and
        # https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-docker-image.html
        # for details.
        idf_ver: ["v4.4.4", "release-v4.4"]
        idf_target: ["esp32"]
    container: espressif/idf:${{ matrix.idf_ver }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: 'recursive'
      - name: esp-idf build
        uses: espressif/esp-idf-ci-action@v1
        with:
            esp_idf_version: ${{ matrix.idf_ver }}
            target: ${{ matrix.idf_target }}
            path: 'main'
```

as an output from logs I receive:

```
Run espressif/esp-idf-ci-action@v1
  with:
    esp_idf_version: v4.4.4
    target: esp32
    path: main
    command: idf.py build
Run export IDF_TARGET=$(echo "esp32" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -d '_-')
  export IDF_TARGET=$(echo "esp32" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -d '_-')
  docker run -t -e IDF_TARGET="${IDF_TARGET}" -v "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}:/app/NightSkySK/mSpaceLock-device" \
  -w "/app/NightSkySK/mSpaceLock-device/main" espressif/idf:v4.4.4 \
  /bin/bash -c 'git config --global --add safe.directory "*" && idf.py build'
  shell: bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
/__w/_temp/43fd574a-8b69-4abc-8986-5b3b2e88aca5.sh: line 2: docker: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

What I did wrong? The same output I got on `release-v4.4'

Comment: Why are you using [`container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) here? https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf-ci-action is a [composite](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf-ci-action/blob/v1/action.yml#L25) action and it is running `docker run` command internally. Looks like `container` configuration is not needed at all in your workflow. Remove it and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong with my github action yaml script, error was result of merging few different files which I wanted combine to match my needs, once I didn't fully understand how it works.
So the problem was at line container: `espressif/idf:${{ matrix.idf_ver }}` which shouldn't be there as it caused that following steps was executed in idf container already.
For long time I couldn't understand why there is docker command to be executed by `espressif/esp-idf-ci-action@v1`. It was intuitive for me that checkout should be executed in idf environment. Once I finally understood that checkout is going to be passed to espressif/esp-idf-ci-action@v1 and only than docker image need to be run than fixing the yaml code become easy task. I will leave my experience here, may be someone will face same issue as me.

Here is the yaml code for github action which is finally working for me:

```
# This is a basic workflow that is manually triggered

name:  Build and Publish Application

# Controls when the action will run. Workflow runs when manually triggered using the UI
# or API.
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches: [main]
  workflow_dispatch:
    # Inputs the workflow accepts.

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  build:
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        # The version names here correspond to the versions of espressif/idf Docker image.
        # See https://hub.docker.com/r/espressif/idf/tags and
        # https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/tools/idf-docker-image.html
        # for details.
        idf_ver: ["release-v4.3", "release-v4.4"]
        idf_target: ["esp32"]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: 'recursive'
      - name: Build Application
        uses: espressif/esp-idf-ci-action@v1
        with:
          esp_idf_version: ${{ matrix.idf_ver }}
          target: ${{ matrix.idf_target }}
      - name: Rename artifact
        run: |
          ls -lah 
          cp build/bootloader/bootloader.bin bootloader-${{ matrix.idf_ver }}.bin
          cp build/partition_table/partition-table.bin partition-table-${{ matrix.idf_ver }}.bin
          cp build/mspacelock.bin mspacelock-${{ matrix.idf_ver }}.bin
          cp build/ota_data_initial.bin ota_data_initial-${{ matrix.idf_ver }}.bin

      - name: Upload
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: mSpaceLock_${{ matrix.idf_target }}_${{ matrix.idf_ver }}
          path: "*-${{ matrix.idf_ver }}.bin"

  release:
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Download Firmware Files
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with:
        path: build
```